# Polymer 2.0 How to extend PolymerElements app-layout and app-drawer

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x, custom-element

I am very new to Polymer 2.0 and I am trying out creating custom elements.

I am able to extend my own custom element and it works fine. I am just trying to find out if I can extend PolymerElements app-layout's app-drawer element found here https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout

I tried this but it is not working.

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-layout.html">

class MyElement extends AppLayout {
  static get is() { return 'my-element'; }
};

customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
```

It gives me an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: AppLayout is not defined`. Even if I tried to make sure that app-layout has correct import script and I can use the app-layout elements like app-drawer.

Is it the name AppLayout that is wrong? I have tried different names like `Polymer.Applayout` etc. but still same error. I have tried extending my own custom element which resides in the same bower_components folder and it works without error.

```
class ExtendedElement extends MyElement {
  static get is() { return 'extended-element'; }
};
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to find something that works [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4556) and [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4683)

This sample will extend `<app-drawer>` element of `<app-layout>`

```
<dom-module id="my-sub-element">
  <template id="styles">
    <style>
      div {
        background-color: gray;
      }
    </style>
  </template>

  <script>

  (function() {
    let subTemplate;

    class MySubElement extends customElements.get('app-drawer') {
      /**
       * This will return our template inherited from superclass <app-drawer> with our styles inserted
       */
      static get template() {
        if (!subTemplate) {
          // first clone our superclass <app-drawer> template
          let superClass = customElements.get('app-drawer');
          subTemplate = superClass.template.cloneNode(true);

          // here we will get the content of our <style> so we can insert them into the superclass <style>
          // note the added id="styles" in our template tag above
          const subStyle = Polymer.DomModule.import('my-sub-element', 'template#styles').content;

          // get the content of current style from superClass
        const superStyle = subTemplate.content.querySelector('style');

          // append our added style at the bottom of the current style to get higher priority
          superStyle.parentNode.appendChild(subStyle);
        }
        return subTemplate;
      }

    }

    customElements.define('my-sub-element', MySubElement);

  })();

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I hope this helps. This is working for me at the moment. I read through this discussion [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4683) to have clearer idea on what is going on when extending . Please add/edit my answer if there is a better way to do this. Cheers!